# Can I post a question asking for feedback on framework?

Tags: support, scope

I am designing a soapUI framework, and I want to know if I can post my design or questions that would create more of a discussion rather than a Q & A format.

Comment: You would have to do that somewhere that is set up for such discussions, like Reddit or Quora.  The Q&A format is something that we're not going to bend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Stack Exchange is not the place for open ended discussions; it is for specifically answerable questions.

However, questions about designing a Soap UI framework would be on topic on the network, **provided that you have a concrete, answerable problem to address**, rather than entering into an open-ended discussion. You can post such questions on the following sites:

- Ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you have a specific question about a problem with your implementation.
- Ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you have working code and a specific question about your design (such as best practices).